# Group Action notation and understanding

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-actions

I've been studying Group Theory for some time, but I still do not understand the appeal of the group action notation. I mean - every time I see: $a \cdot e$, I am thinking, why not just treat $a$ as function on X, and just write $e(a)$ and also instead of $a \cdot gh$, just write $h\circ g(a)$? I mean we already have a symbol for function composition. (We have to reverse the order in this case, right?)

My understanding is, that when $G$ acts on $X$, we are saying that we have a homomorphism from $G$ to a subset of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$. So why not just treat the elements of $G$ as we would treat their images in $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$? That is, just think of $f: G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X) $ and then treat the elements of $G$ as we would treat $\ker(f)g$.

I guess there are some reasons, why things are done as they are, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help.

Comment: When you write $x\cdot y$, which one is the element of $X$ and which one is the element of $G$? Because the notation seems to switch between subsequent iterations of the notion.

Comment: If you just make a group acting on itself by its operation on the left, it would be messy to use a functional notation.

Comment: $x \cdot g$, I am talking about $x$ from $X$ and $g$ from $G$

Comment: Ah, ok. So $a\cdot e$ should be $e(a)$, no?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe it seems bizzare to me to invent a new notation just because many group actions are on the group itself.

Comment: @Gae.S. yes, that's correct

Comment: It seems there are [two conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Definition) for group actions: left group actions and right group actions. The only difference is the order of composition, but without loss of generality you can just stick with one of them. Left group actions are more amenable to your desire to write things as functions, but it seems you have encountered an author who prefers right group actions.

Comment: Hm, I guess I am just confused by the plethora of notations and explanations as for what group actions are. For example in Pinter's book, they are described as subgroups of $S_x$(again annoying, that different books use different name for it - some call it $Sym(x)$, which is not incorrect, I suppose, but then in most other books, they are described as a the dot notation or even a function of $G$ x $X$.

Comment: How would you write the (canonical) action of the integers on an Abelian group?

Comment: Hm, by action of the integers on an abelian group, do you mean powers of elements? I get a that you're saying that it's more convenient to say $g^5$ instead of $^5(g)$.

Comment: The main reason for not thinking of the elements of $G$ as functions $X\to X$ is that we often want the same group to act on several different sets. For example, the group of symmetries of a cube acts on the set of vertices, the set of edges, the set of faces, the set of diagonals, etc.  And sometimes the group elements are most naturally given in the form of something other than functions, for example integers.

Comment: Here's another similar question: What's the appeal of subscript notation for a sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$? Every time you see $x_n$, why not treat $x$ as a function and write $x(n)$?

Comment: More directly, I would say that action notation $g \cdot x$ is nice for a few reasons. First, it has fewer characters, and in particular has fewer parentheses. In writing a long discussion involving lots of group action notation, those extra characters add up and begin to glomp up the text. Second, a group action is not just *any old kind of function*, it is a particularly special kind of function, namely a homomorphism from a group to the isomorphisms of some other mathematical object, and the action notation $g \cdot x$ emphasizes this distinction.

Comment: As far as sequences go, I guess it's just a shorter form, which also normally implies that the indexes belong to the set of the Natural numbers. Ie. with x(n) one would have to think about the domain of x. But I guess I get your point. The new notation highlights the special properties and character of the functions. It just seems a bit counter-intuitive at first to add a new notation for something. Also it's very annoying that different authors have different notations for Group Actions. I can't find the perfect book, so I am trying different ones and the myriad of notations slow the process.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, "$g(x)$" is the ancestor of "$g\cdot x$", when $g$ could be *only* a bijection on $X$ (then more commonly denoted with an $f$ or a $\sigma$). The notion of abstract group action is patterned upon the natural action of the set (forget for now about "groups") of all the bijections on a given set $X$, on this same latter set. Such a natural action, namely $(\sigma,x)\mapsto \sigma(x)$, fulfils the following two basic properties:

1. $Id_X(x)=x, \space\forall x\in X$;
2. $(\sigma\tau)(x)=\sigma(\tau(x)), \space\forall \sigma,\tau\in\operatorname{Sym}(X),\forall x\in X$.

Soon after that $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ has provided the template to draw the definition of abstract group $G$ (the four axioms: closure, associativity, identity, inverse elements), one can be driven by 1 and 2 above, and rise up the following question: does anything interesting come from considering *any map* "$\cdot$" $: G\times X\to X$ *such that (mimicking 1 and 2 above)*:

- $e\cdot x=x, \space\forall x\in X$;
- $(gh)\cdot x=g\cdot(h\cdot x), \space\forall g,h\in G, \forall x\in X$

? In such a more abstract scenario, "$g(x)$" doesn't seem quite sensible, since $g\in G$ isn't any longer, in general, a bijection on $X$.

Comment: Why do you need $g$ to be a bijection for $g(x)$ to be sensible? In general, one can write $g(x)$ for any function $g$. Also how is g not a bijection if G is a subset of Sym(X) or if there is a homomorphism from G to such a subset? I mean suppose $g \cdot x = g \cdot y$. Then we can multiply by $g^{-1}$ and we get $e \cdot x=e \cdot y$ which then implies $x=y$, so it's an injection. Now about surjectivity - since $g \cdot x$ is defined for any x and $g^{-1}$ exists, obv g is surjective.

Comment: Yes, $g(x)$ suits for any function, but here non bijective $g$'s are off topic, as they do not form a group. Yes, $g$'s are bijections if $G\le Sym(X)$, but not every group is a group of permutations, and we want to make actions with any (abstract) group. The existence of action's equivalent homomorphism, say $\varphi$, from $G$ to $Sym(X)$ shows you precisely that *in general* $g\ne\varphi_g$ for the simple reason that, *as sets*, $G\cap Sym(X)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

This notation is also used for deterministic automata, which are just an action of the free monoid on a set $X$. Graphically, composition becomes visually natural with this convention. Just compare the following two lines:
\begin{align}
x \xrightarrow{g} x\cdot g \xrightarrow{h} (x\cdot g) \cdot h \\
x \xrightarrow{gh} x\cdot gh \qquad 
\end{align}

Comment: Well, obv $(x \cdot g) \cdot h$ is equal to $x \cdot gh$. The first line is applying g and then h. While the second line just applies their composition. I am not sure what are the implications of this.

Comment: Nothing special. It just makes the notation natural. Think also of a Cayley graph.